# Command Line utility for MySQL

Tags: command-line, mysql

I want to download only MySQL command line utility. I tried searching but unable to find. I even downloaded the entire MySQL Community edition and tried installing only MySQL Utility but the installer requires Visual Studio c++ 2003.

Could someone help me to download only the required files for MySQL cmd utility?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have mysql.exe itself then I think there is no need for searching any other client. you can find it and load it from the bin folder of mysql installation folder. Try to ownload the zip version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the MySQL installer from 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html. 
From it you can click in the MySQL server version you like to download. On the right hand side you then see the client binaries. The command line utility is in this package. You don't have to install the whole server for installing the client bins.

EDIT: You may have to add the folder with the mysql.exe to the PATH to start it from the command-line.

Comment: Hi, i want to connect to a remoter mysql server and have to kill certain logins every 2 hours. will i be able to do that with this cmd utility? or will i be only able to manage server with this utility? thanks!!

Comment: you will have the standard mysql.exe, that should be capable of doing what you want.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If so, please mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: The option to do a client-only install doesn't seem to be available in the MySQL Community Server MSI any more as of version 8.0.29 in July 2022. As per the installer GUI, the client has a dependency on the server (which doesn't make sense but that's how it's shown). Even though I tricked the installer into having the client selected but not the server it would still proceed to install the server as well.